# Aligning Maths in a Table Column

Tags: tables, align

Is there a way to align this column on *t_p*?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
 $t_p \le -2\; ^\circ\mathrm{C},$                            & frost is expected \\
 $-2\; ^\circ\mathrm{C} \le\, t_p \le 2\; ^\circ\mathrm{C}$ & frost is possible   \\
 $t_p > 2\; ^\circ\mathrm{C}$                                & frost is not expected
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Added from wrong answer:

It is also possible to put every part of this as a separate column in a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
                &       & $t_p$ & $\le$ & $\SI{-2}{\celsius}$ & frost is expected     \\
$\SI{-2}{\celsius}$ & $\le$ & $t_p$ & $\le$ & $\SI{2}{\celsius}$  & frost is possible     \\
                &       & $t_p$ & $>$   & $\SI{2}{\celsius}$  & frost is not expected
\end{tabular}
```

I do not know how to align the 2's in the 4th column, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alignat`, with some trick. I also recommend `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{4}
                  &      && t_p &&\le \SI{-2}{\celsius}, &\quad& \text{frost is expected} \\
\SI{-2}{\celsius} &\le{} && t_p &&\le \SI{2}{\celsius},  &\quad& \text{frost is possible} \\
                  &      && t_p &&>   \SI{2}{\celsius},  &\quad& \text{frost is not expected}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With other tricks and `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{array}{
  r
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  c
  >{{}}c<{{}}
  l
  @{\quad}
  l
}
                  &     & t_p & \le & \SI{-2}{\celsius}, & \text{frost is expected} \\
\SI{-2}{\celsius} & \le & t_p & \le & \SI{2}{\celsius},  & \text{frost is possible} \\
                  &     & t_p & >   & \SI{2}{\celsius},  & \text{frost is not expected}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more column ... for example -- using `array` instead of `tabular`, you can obtain:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{rll}
t_p & \le - \SI{2}{\celsius}     & \text{frost is expected}     \\
- \SI{2}{\celsius}\le t_p  
    & \le \SI{2}{\celsius}      & \text{frost is possible}     \\
t_p & >     \SI{2}{\celsius}     & \text{frost is not expected}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

In above code I use `siunitx` package for units.

Answer (score 1):

A variant with environment `tabbing`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabbing}
  $\SI{-2}{\celsius}<{}$\=$t_p\le\SI{-2}{\celsius}$,\quad\=
  \kill
  \>$t_p\le\SI{-2}{\celsius}$,\>frost is expected\\
  $\SI{-2}{\celsius}<{}$\>$t_p\le\SI{2}{\celsius}$,
      \>frost is possible\\
  \>$t_p>\SI{2}{\celsius}$,\>frost is not possible
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

A simpler code with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 t_p &\le \SI{-2}{\celsius}, &\quad& \text{frost is expected} \\
\SI{-2}{\celsius}\le t_p &\le \SI{2}{\celsius}, & & \text{frost is possible} \\
                    t_p &> \SI{2}{\celsius}, & & \text{frost is not expected}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]